# Printing variable to command line using assembly in Linux

Tags: linux, assembly, nasm

Trying my hand at Linux assembly and I'm running into the following problem.  I'm just starting out so my program is a relatively simple one derived from some examples I found over at linuxassembly. It takes the first argument passed to the command line and prints it out. Here is what I have so far...

```
section .bss
    test_string: resb 3

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    pop ebx     ;argument number
    pop ebx     ;program name
    pop ebx     ;first argument
    mov [test_string],ebx

    mov eax,4
    mov ebx,1
    mov ecx,test_string
    mov edx,3
    int 80h

    mov eax,1
    mov ebx,0
    int 80h
```

I know that this is poorly written, but since I'm new to this, I'm just looking to better understand how assembly instructions/variables work before I move on.  I assemble and link using...

```
nasm -f elf first.asm
ld -m elf_i386 -s -o first first.o
```

Then I run using..

```
./first one two
```

I was thinking that it would print out `one` but it prints out gibberish like `Y*&`. What am I doing wrong? Is my `test_string` the wrong type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to print out the value of the pointer to the string instead of printing the string. You want to do this instead.

```
pop ebx     ;argument number
pop ebx     ;program name
pop ebx     ;pointer to the first argument

mov ecx,ebx ;load the pointer into ecx for the write system call

mov eax,4   ;load the other registers for the write system call
mov ebx,1
mov edx,3
int 80h

mov eax,1
mov ebx,0
int 80h
```

Comment: Ah, I see.  I was loading the pointer to test_string.  So instead I should have done mov ecx, [test_string]

Comment: Why `pop ebx` only to `mov ecx, ebx`? I think you can `pop ecx`, and eliminate the `mov ecx,ebx`.